# Android autoclicker apps that supports multiple tap locations and customizable interval

Tags: android

My friend and me, are looking for Android clicker that can:

- Records multiple tap location
- Sets the interval between taps e.g every 10ms
- Sets repeat count e.g unlimited until stopped / 10 cycles / 10 taps
- Saves/loads configurations of the recorded taps and intervals
- Works without root

Does anyone knows if there is any android app that can do this?

We already tried :

- Automate
- Automatic Clicker
- Automatic Tap - Auto Clicker
- Frep - Finger Replay
- HabiTap - Auto Clicker no Root
- Multi Clicker

Free app is preferred, but I don't mind to pay if the app works wonderfully.
Great apps deserve money anyway.

Comment: What was the problem with each product you tried?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul they either not supporting recording of multiple tap location, or need root access.

Comment: I think it definitely needs root access else you can try this [mouseclicker.net][1][1]: https://mouseclicker.net/